# How can I run bash script without .sh extension?

Tags: linux, bash

```
./advanced_du -a   
bash: ./advanced_du: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "No such file or directory" means exactly that. There's no such file in the current directory. You can't run a file that doesn't exist. Did you name the file `advanced_du` without any extension?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If the file didn't have executable permission the error would be "Permission denied". If it existed and had a syntax error we'd see "bash: line 1: [error]".

Comment: I have #! shebang

Comment: And bash ./advanced_du do not work

Comment: @JohnKugelman my file has .sh extention but want to run  without .sh

Comment: The shebang doesn't matter if there is no file from which to read it. If the file is named `advanced_du.sh`, you *can't* run it as `advanced_du`. You have to rename the file.

Answer (score 3):

Rename `advanced_du.sh` to `advanced_du` with no extension.

```
mv advanced_du.sh advanced_du
```

Comment: Or add `.sh` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. That's the solution I was looking for